# What is the name of this mating motif?

Tags: checkmate, terminology, patterns

[image]

Anyone know the name of this motif? I have seen it several times, but never knew the name. Source Polgar 5334 problems.

Can one classify this as a Legal's trap motif due to the *famous* Queen sacrifice(Bxd1)?

Comment: 1.Nf6 gxf6 2. Bxf7?  You might get more answers if the reader doesn't have to solve the puzzle

Comment: @Edward, I am sure if a user can't solve this puzzle they will not know the answer :).

Comment: looks like a variant of legal :D

Comment: This position can arise after

1 e4 e5 2 Nf3 Nc6 3 Bb5 a6 4 Ba4 b5 5 Bb3 d6 6 Nc3 Bg4 7 Nd5 Na5 8 c3 Ne7 9 Nxe5 Bxd1

It is indeed a bit like Légall's mate, but it's come about in a strange way. More usually, Légall's mate involves Bxf7+, but here, so long as White has wNd5, White does not threaten Bxf7+. White's attack works only because bNe7 blocks bKe8, so it could be seen as White punishing Ne7? (instead of Nf6). So it was handy for White that they'd earlier played Nd5, which would otherwise have been a bad move.

Comment: Not everything has to have a name ... Just remember the pattern, that's the important thing.

Comment: @Akavall Perhaps, but if a user knows the answer that doesn't mean they'll care to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

The move Nxe5 echoes the famous game by Legal, because if black captures the queen, checkmate is then unavoidable. However, I would classify this motif as a `discovered attack`(which includes checkmate itself). There is some more useful information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovered_attack#:%7E:text=This%20scenario%20is%20often%20referred,checkmate%20itself%20is%20also%20possible.)

In the OP, the discovered attack is 1.Nf6+, which is followed by 2.Bxf7#